# In Yii, why the tutorials reference the classes methods with ::

Tags: php, yii

It's a simple question but since I am a beginner, it confuses me.

In the tutorials, for example: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao it references methods like this:

> 1. Executing SQL Statements
>
> Once a database connection is established, SQL statements can be
>   executed using CDbCommand. One creates a CDbCommand instance by
>   calling CDbConnection::createCommand() with the specified SQL
>   statement:

But in the specification http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection#createCommand-detail it says  `public CDbCommand createCommand(mixed $query=NULL)`

As far as I know the `::` are for static methods/properties.

I know I am missing something because they use this format everywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: It's just a way of showing that a method belongs to a particular class. Code examples show that the method is called on an instance: `$command=$connection->createCommand($sqlStatement);` http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbConnection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, [*Paamayim Nekudotayim*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) `::` is used just to point out that a method is part of a class : method `createCommand` is a `CDbConnection` method, but this does not mean that you have to use it as static.